# How can I make a batch file that runs an exe at startup by adding it to windows registry?

Tags: windows, registry, startup

I got a python app, i compile it with pyinstaller and works perfectly, i got the file "MyApp.exe", but i want it to run at startup by adding the app to the registry, using the os.system module, that allows me to run batch commands.

> How can I make a batch file that runs an exe at startup by adding it
>   to windows registry ?

Supposing that the exe is calles `"MyApp.exe"` and is located in `D:\\Apps\`, **how can i get it done ?**

Comment: Use REG ADD. Type `REG ADD /?` for help.

Comment: could you make an example of how to use it for my purpose, i already know the location, `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`